# How to check if an optional workflow_dispatch input is set or not

Tags: github-actions

I have an input defined as

```
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      level:
        description: 'level to process'
        type: number
        required: false
```

I would like to run named actions in the step depending on if the value is set or not but I cannot figure how

This might be working:

```
  if: ${{ github.event.inputs.level}}
```

But I cannot find the opposite version, this is invalid:

```
  if: !${{ github.event.inputs.level}}
```

Comment: Try `${{ g.e.i.level != "" }}`

Comment: @jessehouwing I tried  but I get "get Unexpected symbol: '""' "

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I've tested it in [this workflow](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester22.yml) and the correct way to check if an input (or any variable) is empty or not in an IF conditional is by using the following syntax:

```
if: "${{ github.event.inputs.<INPUT_NAME> != '' }}"
```

Note: using `!= ""` will break the workflow as the interpreter doesn't accept this symbol in expressions.

Therefore, your workflow would look like this:

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      level:
        description: 'level to process'
        type: number
        required: false

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Print variable if not empty
        if: "${{ github.event.inputs.level != '' }}"
        run: echo Level value is ${{ github.event.inputs.level }}

      - name: Print message if empty
        if: "${{ github.event.inputs.level == '' }}"
        run: echo Level value is empty
```

I've made two tests here if you want to check (links may lead to not found page through time):

- [workflow run with empty input value](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/runs/5125444597?check_suite_focus=true)
- [workflow run with not empty input value](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/runs/5125439914?check_suite_focus=true)

Comment: How about a Boolean input?

Comment: Shouldn't a boolean input only be true or false (using the default value)? 

Comment: Yes. That doesn't change the fact that we want to use the provided value when available. If the provided value is false and the default true, ${{ inputs.mybool || true }} would return true regardless of a false input value. For now, I've landed on `${{ inputs.value > '' && inputs.value || mydefault`

Comment: This syntax is quite verbose indeed. It almost seems easier to use an input of the list type (with options) instead of a boolean in that case 